# Spring http client: pkcs12 keystore and trustsrtore on httpclient

Tags: java, spring, ssl

Into my application I'm using an `HttpClient` setting an ssl context:

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
        .loadKeyMaterial(
            new URL(schedulerConfiguration.getKeyStore()),
            schedulerConfiguration.getKeyStorePassword().toCharArray(),
            schedulerConfiguration.getKeyPassword().toCharArray()
        )
        .loadTrustMaterial(
            new URL(schedulerConfiguration.getTrustStore()),
            schedulerConfiguration.getTrustStorePassword().toCharArray()
        )
        .build();

    return HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();      
}
```

As you can see I'm loading a keystore and a truststore.

`keystore` contains the private key and `truststore` contains all chain certificates.

I'm running against client connections can't be launched due to:

> Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: **I/O error on GET request for "https://balancer:8080/token"**: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**
>
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**
>
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**
>
> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

I've built my jks from a `.p12` file like this.

In order to build trsutstore:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in fitxers.p12 -nokeys -out cacerts-nokeys.crt
$ keytool -importcert -file cacerts-nokeys.crt -keystore cacerts-pre-splitted.jks
```

And in order to create my keystore:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore fitxers.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore auth-backoffice-pre.jks -deststoretype jks
```

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having similar issue when not using aliases properly. Are you using aliases in your original p12 file? If so, I'd recommend using the other method for loading the key material with custom PrivateKeyStrategy.

Also take a look when trying to connect your client with vm option:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

You will be able to see a bit of more information. Hopefully this guides you to your solution!